# Find latitude and longitude based on image which is displaying

Tags: android, geolocation, latitude-longitude

Hi I am new to android development.

Need to find list of latitude and longitude in between two points. 
I need implement above calculation to an image which is 600X600 and also i need to find latitude,longitude of any x,y position in image.
And also i add some sample image which is help to understand my problem.

Over the past days i search the google, i found so many links to find distance between locations and mid point. I cant able to find solution for my problem.

Please suggest some solution for this problem. I am struggling over days to find solution for this.

Thanks in advance[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5wBE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

For me you have to do a proposition with existing points to find the relationship between x,y coordinates and lat,long coordinates